# htaccess 404 error conditional code for 301 redirect

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have paginated URLs that look like `http://www.domain.com/tag/apple/page/1/`

If a URL such as `http://www.domain.com/tag/apple/page/*2/` doesn't exist, or `page/2` doesn't exist, I need code to redirect this to a page such as `http://www.domain.com/tag/apple/` which would be the main tag page.

I've currently have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain.com/tag/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/page/([0-9]*)/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/tag/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

In this code, if the URL does not exist it redirects to the main tag page, but its not working.

Does anybody have an hints or solutions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, you are saying that you have a list of rewritten URLs (using `mod_rewrite`); some of them exist, some of them don't. With the ones that *don't* exist, you want them to be redirected to a new page location?

The short-answer is, you can't do that within `htaccess`. When you're working with `mod_rewrite`, your rewritten page names are passed to a controller file that translates the rewritten URL to what page/content it's supposed to display.

I'm only assuming you're using PHP, and if so, most PHP frameworks (CakePHP, Drupal, LithiumPHP, etc.) can take care of this issue for you and handle custom redirects for non-existing files. If you have a custom-written application, you'll need to handle the redirect within the PHP website and not in the `.htaccess` file.

A *very* simple example of this would be:

```
<?php
function getTag($url) {
    if (preg_match('|/tag/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/|', $url, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    }
    return '';
}

function validateUrl($url) {
    if (preg_match('|/tag/([0-9a-zA-Z]*)/page/([0-9]*)/|', $url, $match)) {
        $tag = $match[1];
        $page = $match[2];
        $isValid = // your code that checks if it's a URL/page that exists
        return $isValid;
    }
    return false;
}

if (!validateUrl($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    $tag = getTag($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location /tag/' . $tag . '/');
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: Friend, im using Wordpress... How i use this code in wordpress filter? if 'tag/apple/page/2/' not exist redirect to 'tag/apple/' page?

Comment: @user1218948 I'm not familiar with WordPress, but this [plugin, **Redirection**,](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) looks really helpful (it's first "new feature" sounds like exactly what you want).